# How do I get Google Closure to call my init function when DOM tree finished

Tags: javascript, initialization, google-closure-library

I am looking for something like the `$(document).ready` function in jQuery, as I work on experimenting with using Closure.

So, my question is simple, is there a function I am missing that will allow me to wait until my function is called when the DOM tree is done?

I use unobtrusive javascript, so the idea of putting any javascript in my html is such a negative, if that is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're out of luck according to [this](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41?hl=en&pli=1). Inline script blocks appears to be your only choice.

Comment: Weird. Why would they want the user to start poking around before the page is ready?

Comment: Thank you. :(  I guess I will use my standard javascript snippet for this functionality, but, this is annoying that they did it intentionally.

Comment: There is some sense to that actually, a lot of what is loaded on a page isn't used/necessary until later. Getting the page responsive with the most common elements loading first would make for a better UI, and Google does have some of the more responsive web apps.

Comment: Maybe. I just played around in Google Docs and it looked like I had a busy cursor until everything was ready anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it your way (instead of Google's way), perhaps this would work for you.

[Cross Browser JavaScript DOMContentLoaded](http://www.integralist.co.uk/2009/11/cross-browser-javascript-domcontentloaded/)

Comment: Thank you. I have a snippet of code I have been using for about 3 years that works fine, and I just tried it in my first application, it printed "Hello World!". :)